LC3 Optimizing XOR and OR gate implementation
I was given a challenge to implement a XOR gate in only 5 instructions, and a OR gate in only 3 instructions (while with the first line setting the starting memory address to x3000 and the final line being HALT).
I am struggling with how to thing of this challenge, since the only way I've been able to do it is use DeMorgan's theorem to represent XOR and OR with NAND gates, since LC3 only has AND and NOT operations. If I follow that, I can implement the XOR gate in 8 instructions and the OR gate in 4 instructions. Are there any hints?

For inspiration on how to use And and Not operations to simulate an XOR check out the following post which has a gate diagram: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487529/build-an-xor-gate-from-and-not   When you code this in LC3 you'll do similar boolean  expressions in LC3; also, you may have a few commands to load data.

OR in 3: a + (~a & b)

Let's first point out that addition is very close to an OR operation, but includes a carry feature, which, if it can be avoided then degenerates to simple OR.  So, these answers are fairly spcific to LC-3 (using only not, and, add).
(Addition like shown in these answers would not normally be used in hardware circuitry — why build a more complex operation only to avoid using the carry.)
XOR



a
b
~a
~b
a&~b
b&~a
(a&~b)+(b&~a)
a xor b




0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0


0
1
1
0
0
1
1
1


1
0
0
1
1
0
1
1


1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0



The last column is XOR directly, while the one before is a formula using only what LC-3 has.
The expression a&~b isolates one case where we want XOR to be true, while the reverse, b&~a isolates the other case.
Since the two cases never happen together, we can can combine them with ADD working for us here as an OR operation — ADD is OR though with carry, which will never happen in this usage.
Can do this on LC-3 in 5 instructions.

OR
Thanks to @Sebastian



a
b
~a
~a&b
a+(~a&b)
a or b




0
0
1
0
0
0


0
1
1
1
1
1


1
0
0
0
1
1


1
1
0
0
1
1



The last column is OR directly, while the one before is a formula using only what LC-3 has.
Can do this on LC-3 in 3 instructions.
Another well known formula is ~(~a&~b) though for 4 instructions.

Thank you for your thoughtful answer, this helps a lot to understand the process. OR in 3 instructions seems very difficult to do, which I'll try to figure out.
